# Read json file 'Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : lexical error: invalid char in json text'

Tags: r, jsonlite

I'm having the following problem with `jsonlite::fromJSON` function.
This is a reproducible example

```
tmp <- tempfile()
url <- "http://dadosabertos.c3sl.ufpr.br/curitibaurbs/2019_10_01_tabelaVeiculo.json.xz"
download.file(url, destfile =tmp,quiet = FALSE, mode = "w")
wb <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp)
```

I'm getting this error

```
wb <- jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp)
# Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
#   lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#           4444444444444444444444444},{"COD_LINHA":"519","NOME_LINHA":"
#                      (right here) ------^
# In addition: Warning message:
# In readBin(3L, raw(0), 32768L) : lzma decoder corrupt data
```

This is my session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (build 9600)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    # LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
# [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
# [1] compiler_4.0.1 tools_4.0.1    jsonlite_1.7.0
```

---

The reproducible code worked in my Linux, which had this following session info, but I still not sure what causes the error.

```
> sessionInfo()
# R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1
# 
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8       
#  [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
# [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         rstudioapi_0.11    magrittr_1.5       hms_0.5.3         
#  [5] units_0.6-7        tidyselect_1.1.0   lattice_0.20-41    R6_2.4.1          
#  [9] rlang_0.4.7        stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.0        tools_4.0.2       
# [13] rgdal_1.5-12       grid_4.0.2         data.table_1.13.0  KernSmooth_2.23-17
# [17] e1071_1.7-3        DBI_1.1.0          ellipsis_0.3.1     class_7.3-17      
# [21] tibble_3.0.3       lwgeom_0.2-5       lifecycle_0.2.0    sf_0.9-5          
# [25] crayon_1.3.4       zip_2.0.4          readr_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.4       
# [29] gtfs2gps_1.2-3     vctrs_0.3.2        glue_1.4.1.9000    openxlsx_4.1.5    
# [33] sp_1.4-2           stringi_1.4.6      compiler_4.0.2     pillar_1.4.6      
# [37] generics_0.0.2     classInt_0.4-3     jsonlite_1.7.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Comment: use  `mode = "wb"` instead of `mode = "w"`

Comment: this worked!! Thank you! Still don't know why this happened on Windows and not Linux

Comment: For an explanation, read the last few sentences of the details section of `help("download.file")`.

Answer (score 0):

according to ritchie-sacramento above, we can use `mode = "wb"` instead of `mode = "w"`

```
>  help("download.file")
```

see
`mode`

`character. The mode with which to write the file. Useful values are "w", "wb" (binary), "a" (append) and "ab". Not used for methods "wget" and "curl". See also ‘Details’, notably about using "wb" for Windows.`